# Refactoring a foreach to functional programming

Tags: php, foreach, functional-programming, array-map

I'm refactoring some code to functional programming for readability and I encounter a problem with an array. I want to change an array of objects to a simple array with arrays of values.

The first array looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  [5701]=>
  object(stdClass)#123 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5701"
    ["username"]=>
    string(6) "s67688"
    ["state"]=>
    string(6) "Inactive"    
  }
  [5762]=>
  object(stdClass)#136 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "5762"
    ["username"]=>
    string(6) "s67701"
    ["state"]=>
    string(6) "Active"
  }  
}
```

I want to convert it into something like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    id(4) 5701
    [1]=>
    string(6) "s67688"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Inactive"    
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(4) 5762
    [1]=>
    string(6) "s67701"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Active"    
  }
}
```

With a simple foreach it is easy to achieve but when i try the following code:

```
$newArr = array_map(function($value){
               return array_values(get_object_vars($value));
          }, $baseArr);
```

The output is the following:

```
array(2) {
  [5701]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    id(4) 5701
    [1]=>
    string(6) "s67688"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Inactive"    
  }
  [5762]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    int(4) 5762
    [1]=>
    string(6) "s67701"
    [2]=>
    string(8) "Active"    
  }
}
```

As you can see the base array keys are not changing, why is this happening?

This is the original foreach which returns what i want:

```
$newArr = [];
foreach ($baseArr as $value) {
     $newArr[] = array_values(get_object_vars($user));
}
```

I've also tried array_walk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_map` applies a callback to the values and does not modify the keys.  I also simplified getting the values by just casting to `array`:

```
$newArr = array_values(array_map(function($v){
                                     return array_values((array)$v);
                                 }, $baseArr));
```

You can use the `array_values` after as above, or before:

```
$newArr = array_map(function($v){
                        return array_values((array)$v);
                    }, array_values($baseArr));
```

I personally would keep it as an associative array:

```
$newArr = array_values(array_map(function($v){ return (array)$v; }, $baseArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a library then this can be done easily using [Tarsana Functional](https://github.com/tarsana/functional)

```
use Tarsana\Functional as F;
$newArr = F\value(F\map(F\values(), $baseArr));
```

**Note** I am the writer of that library